# In eclipse, when running jUnit tests, how can I quickly skip to my class in the Failure Trace in the jUnit View?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

Sometimes, as below, the exception that ends a test bubbles up from deep in a stack trace, with my class(es) somewhere in the middle or sometimes multiple places.  The only way I know how to find my code is by right click -> copying the trace (or Ctrl + c), and then searching for it in another window.

Is there a way to quickly skip to my classes with a shortcut?

[image]

Comment: For me, it works just to double-click the appropriate line of the stack trace, inside the JUnit view.

Comment: That takes me to the corresponding line in the code, but that doesn't give me the exception itself.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "give me the exception", but one useful technique is to set an exception breakpoint on the particular exception type.

Comment: I see what you mean; my code may or may not be associated with the exception in cases like this.  I was just trying to find my own code within the stack trace, so see it in context.

Comment: Right.  I usually scroll down the stack trace till I see my domain name at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Which is easy to miss in hundreds of lines.  Hence the question.  :)

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thought you were asking how to get from the stack trace to the actual source code.  You might want to clarify that that is what you meant.  Honestly, I've never had a problem scrolling down a few hundred lines of stack, and noticing when the domain name changes.  Although I admit that using Spring makes it (and many other things) more difficult than it should be.